# Incorrect tax price calculation

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, price, tax

I am trying to achieve a price calculation with tax like follows.

- Product price in magento admin (without tax): 74.78
- Tax: 19%
- Price + tax: 88.9882.
- **I need rounding of product price 2 digits**. Display on website: 88.99, when calculating total price use 88.99 * number_of_products

The problem is when I add 10 products in shopping cart, total price for product is 889.91. From where there is that 1cent? It should display 889.90.

Tax calculation settings:

[image: Tax calculation settings]

## Update 1

I placed an order of 1000 items, opened Paypal window to pay and there was: Item price: €**7.478,10**. How could it be with 10 cent more if price in magento is 74.78?

Comment: There are many rounding bugs in older Magento versions. So first of all we need to know which version you are using.

Comment: @Jaymz, CE 1.7.0.2

Comment: I don't understand something. Your config says `Catalog Prices: Including Tax`, but in the question you say `Product price in magento admin (without tax): 74.78`. Just to make it clear, what is the value of the `Price` field of your product?

Comment: In admin, `Price` field of my product is 74.78. Tax class is a custom one.

Answer (score 2):

As **Marius** pointed out, my config says `Catalog Prices: Including Tax`, but in magento admin products were (without tax) and a custom class tax was applied. Changed in config `Tax → Catalog Prices` to `Excluding Tax`, and my problem is resolved.